# How to Force a Flex Chart to Redraw During Runtime

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I have a column chart that uses a label function to format the vertical axis. I added a button and want the axis (or chart) to redraw when the button is clicked. Right now, the chart axis renders OK only when initially added to the view state.

I have a function that sets various properties after the chart is initially created. In there, I have tried all these:

`myChart.verticalAxis.dataChanged();

myChart.validateNow();

myChart.validateDisplayList();

myChart.validateProperties();

myChart.invalidateDisplayList();

myChart.invalidateProperties();`

But they do not change the axis formatting. How can I do this?

The MXML code for the axis is:

`< mx:LinearAxis id="verticalAxis" labelFunction="vAxisFormat"/>`

The label function is:

```
    private function vAxisFormat(labelValue:Number, previousValue:Object, axis:IAxis):String {
        axis.getLabelEstimate();
        if (_scale == 1){
            return currencyFormatter.format(labelValue/_scale); 
        }else {
            return numberFormatter.format(labelValue/_scale);
        }   
    }
```

Comment: normally it will work If you reassign "verticalAxis.labelFunction=vAxisFormat" on that button click.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the data provider. This redraws the graph, so all the components.

Example:

ArrayCollection
arr.refresh ();

XML
char.dataprovider = xmlData

regars